# Why SonarLint is showing issue on the method name?

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarlint

SonarLint is showing an issue like this below :

> Refactor this method to reduce its cognitive complexiety from 29 to
> the 15 allowed.

**Note:** This error message is given on the method `getOrderBagDetails()`.

Snippet of `getOrderBagDetails()` method is given below :

```
@Override
public DataResponse getProductBagDetails(Integer userId) throws Exception {
    logger.info("in getOrderBagDetails with userid : {}", userId);
    else {
        logger.info("fetching order bag details");
    }
}
```

Why is it happening and how to solve it ?

Comment: Looks like invalid code, where is the if? Is that a typo?

Comment: The cognitive complexity rule has nothing to do with the method's name but with the methods contents. The TLDR version is the method contains too much stuff to be easly read and understand. Try extracting some of the method's code into separate methods and the complexity count will go down